Merge Statement with Select query as input not working in AWS Athena
I am writing the following merge query in AWS Athena, according to the documentation a table or a query can be input to the merge statement.
I have a iceberg table in Athena that needs to be inserted when a new table timestamp is received, but for an existing table the time should be updated.
WITH temporaryTable (database_name, table_name, max_redshift_timestamp) AS (
    select 'iddna' as database_name, 'TEAM_DIM' as table_name, timestamp '2024-08-21 12:33:59.000001' as max_redshift_timestamp
)
MERGE INTO derived_load_support.redshift_last_processed_dttm as t
USING temporaryTable as s
ON s.database_name=t.database_name and s.table_name=t.table_name
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET (max_redshift_timestamp = s.max_redshift_timestamp )
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (database_name, table_name, max_redshift_timestamp) VALUES (s.database_name, s.table_name, s.max_redshift_timestamp)

I have also tried without the CTS, I am getting the same error
MERGE INTO derived_load_support.redshift_last_processed_dttm as t
USING select 'iddna' as database_name, 'TEAM_DIM' as table_name, timestamp '2024-08-21 12:33:59.000001' as max_redshift_timestamp as s
ON s.database_name=t.database_name and s.table_name=t.table_name
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET (max_redshift_timestamp = s.max_redshift_timestamp )
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (database_name, table_name, max_redshift_timestamp) VALUES (s.database_name, s.table_name, s.max_redshift_timestamp)

In both the cases, I am getting this error

line 2:7: mismatched input 'select'. Expecting: '(', 'LATERAL', 'TABLE', 'UNNEST', 

Any help in this regard will be great.

Try wrapping the select into parenthesis: (select 'iddna' as database_name, 'TEAM_DIM' as table_name, timestamp '2024-08-21 12:33:59.000001' as max_redshift_timestamp) as s though doubt that this will work. Other than that  - just inline the variables

@GuruStron I have tried using the parenthesis, I get the same error. What do you mean inline the variables ?

Use like this
MERGE INTO derived_load_support.redshift_last_processed_dttm as t
USING ( select 'iddna' as database_name, 'TEAM_DIM' as table_name, timestamp '2024-08-21 12:33:59.000001' as max_redshift_timestamp) as s
ON s.database_name=t.database_name and s.table_name=t.table_name
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET (max_redshift_timestamp = s.max_redshift_timestamp )
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (database_name, table_name, max_redshift_timestamp) VALUES (s.database_name, s.table_name, s.max_redshift_timestamp)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
